# Some trouble as a beginner

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am having a problem, I need to get a value just as a string but I have a pandas serie, and if I index the serie I get and object, and if I cast to str() I get brackets and other characters too. How can i get just the value as a string?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkqWK.png)

I am just expecting the string "Gear" not all the information

Comment: `df_merged.iloc[0]`, btw your `"df"` is a **Series**

Comment: I did it but this will give you the value 1904 but not the string of the index

Comment: then `df_merged.index[0]`